# Dynamic components. Fragment navigation overwrites URL

Tags: angular, router, angular-dynamic-components

I create component dynamically with:

```
createComponent(componentType, {
      environmentInjector: this.appRef.injector,
      elementInjector: parentComponent.injector
    });
```

The template looks like this:

```
<a [routerLink]="'./'" [fragment]="myFragment"</a>
```

On link click I want it to scroll to the element.
The problem is that the link generated looks like this:

```
http://localhost:4200/#myFragment
```

instead of:

```
http://localhost:4200/someUrl/otherPartofUrl/#myFragment
```

The url is being overwritten.
In components that are not created dynamically it works fine.
Is there any way I can achieve that?

Comment: So I did it by injecting `router` into the component and passed ulr to `[routerLink]` like this `[routerLink]=router.url [fragment]="myFragment"`. Im not sure if this is the best approach.